# Reading document tags from C# application on Windows server 2008

Tags: c#, ms-office, metadata

I am currently working on a project that reads the "tag" meta data from MS Office documents.  I used the API Code Pack which works like a dream on Windows 7.....but when I moved the app to the 08 server, it is only recognizing tags on pre-2007 file format files (those without the .***X file name).  I have seen similar issue with windows 7 64 bit, but this "server" is a 32 bit machine?!  Anyone know of a work-around, another way of accessing the "tags", or even heard of such a thing?

here is the code used to get at the tags:

```
var shellFile = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellFile.FromFilePath(p_Path);
var rawTags = (string[])shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.ValueAsObject;
rawTags = rawTags ?? new string[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a Windows 7 versus Server 2008 problem at all. Do you have Office installed on the PC you were testing it with? You may need to have Office installed on the server for it to recognize docx. Alternatively, you might be able to try using the Word Viewer instead of a full install of Office.

Comment: Installing office worked. You are an officer and gentleman James. Thanks.  Just when I thought I had tried everything.